# Update Oracle Table using rownum and order by

Tags: sql, oracle

Im trying to update a field in an oracle table, but I would only like to update 75 rows based on the order by creationdate field ascending.

This is what I have so far, but its not working.

```
UPDATE extractcandidate
SET process = 15
WHERE process IN
(Select process from extractcandidate where process = 1500 and rownum <=75 order by creationdate);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Gordon mentioned, you need to do the `ORDER BY` before the `ROWNUM`.

Firstly, order by `creationdate`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM extractcandidate
 WHERE process=1500
 ORDER BY creationdate;
```

Secondly, limit the number to 75:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (
        SELECT *
          FROM extractcandidate
         WHERE process=1500
         ORDER BY creationdate
       ) 
  WHERE rownum <= 75;
```

Now you can feed it into the `UPDATE`. To find the correct rows, you would normally use a primary key column. This seems to be missing in your case, so you can fall back to Oracle's internal `ROWID`:

```
UPDATE extractcandidate 
   SET process=15
 WHERE rowid IN (
                 SELECT ri 
                   FROM (
                         SELECT rowid as ri
                           FROM extractcandidate
                          WHERE process=1500
                          ORDER BY creationdate
                         ) 
                  WHERE rownum <= 75
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an additional subquery for your method to work:

```
UPDATE extractcandidate
    SET process = 15
    WHERE ec.process = 1500 AND
          creationdate IN (SELECT ec.creationdate
                           FROM (SELECT ec.*
                                 FROM extractcandidate ec 
                                 WHERE ec.process = 1500 
                                 ORDER BY ec.creationdate
                                )
                           WHERE rownum <= 75
                          );
```

Notes:

- You need to do the sorting before using `rownum`.
- The comparison needs to be on creation date, not `process`.

Comment: ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER

Comment: its strange, for some reason its updating 84 rows.  Not sure why??

Comment: Presumably, you want to limit updates to `process = 1500`, although this is not mentioned in your original question.